# Open file in new buffer in NERDTree?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I’m just getting used to NERDTree and Vim.

I currently have one file open in a buffer. How do I get NERDTree to open another file in a buffer to the right?

If I just navigate to the file in NERDTree and press <kbd>enter</kbd>, then the file opens in the same buffer. I’d like to have two files open at once.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

When you press `?` in the NERDTree sidebar, you'll get a help of all the available commands.

Among them (in their default config) are `i` for a split and `s` for a vertical split.

You can read all about those in the detailed `:help NERDTreeMappings`; it's also possible to re-assign them, should those keys not match your taste.

Answer (score 1):

When you preview the file, the file is added to your buffer list. The current file is in the hidden buffer, you can use `ls` to see your buffer list. If you want the file in another window, as Ingo-Karkat pointed out you can use `i: open split` horizontal split and `s: open vsplit` in a vertical split.

Here are the shortcuts

```
" File node mappings~
" double-click,
" o: open in prev window
" go: preview
" t: open in new tab
" T: open in new tab silently
" middle-click,
" i: open split
" gi: preview split
" s: open vsplit
" gs: preview vsplit
" <CR>: custom open
```

You can use `?` to see NerdTree shortcuts.